# Getting CanvasUrl is null or empty with facebook api for .NET and canvas application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

just getting started with facebook api in .net , any one know how i can set my canvas url, it has been set in the application in facebook and here is my code

```
public class HomeController : BaseController
{
    [CanvasAuthorize(Permissions = "email")]
    public ActionResult Contest()
    { //Do something with authoized user session }
```

i am using .net 4.0 and mvc3

thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set two properties in the webConfig file of your application. In the **facebookSettings** section set **canvasUrl** and **canvasPage**.